# Complex queries vs storing more data

Tags: mongodb, meteor, bigdata, database

I'm having an hard time deciding what's the better approach when figuring how what I want to have in my application. I mostly use MongoDB, and work on web applications, if it can make the answer more specific.

I wonder what will be a better approach:

1. Store as little data as possible in Mongo's collections, and implement my different features mainly with server side logic and calculations against the stored data.
2. Store anything I need for a feature, to avoid complex queries and logic in server side functions, while filling my Mongo with lots of information.

Because of lack of experince (I'm only beginning my way as web developer), I believe, I can't figure out which approach should I take. I thought about taking the second one while prototyping, but switching while starting to scale might be too much effort. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a hard question to answer actually. I would focus security first then try to send as much data to the client as possible, within reason*. It depends on the amount of data you're working with and how the client will navigate through the site basically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing a 3rd option:

3. Store little data in the collection, do calculations on the client.

The beauty of meteor comes with the tech shift to thick clients. Back in the day, primarily prior to V8, browsers couldn't do much. Now, they can do a crazy amount of work. By pushing the work to your clients, you take processing workload off your server, you don't have to save calculated fields to your DB, and often times `client processing time < server processing time + transmission time`.

If you can't do option #3, lean towards #2. Storage is generally cheaper (and definitely faster) than processing power, but it depends on the complexity of the query. If storage cost < processing cost, store it.

`array.toString()`? calculate it. Neural network simulation? store it.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! You gave me some percpectives to look at.